# Kotlin Multiplatform - Error in multiparts using ktor

Tags: kotlin, multipart, kotlin-multiplatform, ktor

I have an error when receiving the body parts of the multi-part request

The back is receiving a null key and all the parameters inside an array as value. I need a key value for each parameter

[image]

My code to send the multipart is the following

````
```
suspend inline fun<reified T> _postMultiPart(microservice: String,
                                         function: String,
                                         parameters: HashMap<String, Any?>,
                                         partsData: HashMap<String, Any?>,
                                         domain: String = MySharedPreferences().escuela
): T {

return httpClient.post(Constants.ROOT_URL+ microservice+function) {
    parameters.forEach {
        parameter(it.key, it.value)
    }
    body = MultiPartFormDataContent(
            formData {
                partsData.forEach {
                    append(it.key, it.value.toString())
                }
            }
      )
       headers {
           append("referer", Constants.HEADER_REFERER+function)
           append("dominio_app", domain)
       }
   }
}
```
````

Comment: The related Youtrack issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTOR-1596